# consulta PHP-JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

Después de sus comentarios logro obtenerlos de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

$id = $_POST['id'];

$packing = PackingListData::getPackingList($id);
$arr = array();   
foreach ($packing as $pack) {
                $arr[] = array(
                    "data"=>array(  
                                    'id'=>$pack->id,
                                    'referencia' =>$pack->referencia,
                                    'estilo'=>$pack->estilo,
                                    'bultos'=>$pack->bultos,
                )
              );

}
echo  json_encode($arr);

 ?>
```

Aqui muestra en mi console.log(data):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi funcion js donde trato de mostrar esos datos:

```
function obtenerPacking(id){

    $.post("index.php?action=getPackingList",{id:id},function(data){

        console.log(data);

        var table = $("#tblListado").DataTable({
                "ajax":{
                    "method":"POST",
                    "dataType":"json"
                    "url";""
                },
                "colums":[
                        {"data":"id"},
                        {"data":"referencia"},
                        {"data":"estilo"},
                        {"data":"bultos"},
                        ]

            });

    })


}
```

y me genera un conflicto desde $.post con mi url, como puedo agregar mi argumento.

Comment: por que no imprimes el arreglo al final esta dentro del for , tambien en la asignacion deberias de haccer algo como $arr[] = array()

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow, efectivamente era eso, gracias se le agradece.

Comment: Agrega `JSON.parse(someJSONString)` en el JS, con esto obtendrás un array y así puedas iterar y acceder a los datos de cada registro.

Comment: Gracias @ÁngelHernández, efectivamente estoy realizando de esa pero muestra [object Object]. Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cada iteración de tu bucle estás imprimiendo la salida de `json_encode`. Esto lo recibe javascript como

```
{"foo1":"bar1"}{"foo2":"bar2"}
```

Que no es json válido. Lo que debieras hacer es meter todas las filas en un array y luego imprimir la salida del json_encode:

```
$arr = array();   

foreach ($packing as $pack) {

// Añado una fila al array
$arr[] = array( 'id'=>$pack->id,
                'referencia' =>$pack->referencia,
                'estilo'=>$pack->estilo,
                'bultos'=>$pack->bultos,

              );

}
// imprimo sólo cuando terminé de iterar
echo  json_encode($arr);
```

Esto imprimirá

```
[{"foo1":"bar1"},{"foo2":"bar2"}]
```

que sí es un arreglo json válido.

Comment: efectivamente asi lo realice, ahora para tomar los datos json desde js, el JSON.parse(data) obtengo este error Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. Con este apartado obtengo mi JSON  $.post("index.php?action=getPackingList",{id:id},function(data){ console.log(data);})

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu pregunta mostrando qué te llega en la respuesta? O más bien, qué imprime tu console.log?